# Error in Setting Up LangChain Custom LLM Pipeline - "CUDA out of memory" in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, langchain

I am currently working on setting up a custom LLM pipeline for LangChain using [its documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/llms/custom_llm), and specifically using the "[upstage/llama-65b-instruct](https://huggingface.co/upstage/llama-65b-instruct)" for the LLM. While experimenting with upstages [sample code](https://huggingface.co/upstage/llama-65b-instruct#usage), I have ensured that my GPUs have sufficient capacity to load and utilize this specific LLM.

However, when attempting to follow LangChain's custom LLM instructions, I am encountering an error:

```
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 64.00 MiB (GPU 0; 23.64 GiB total capacity; 22.79 GiB already allocated; 42.50 MiB free; 23.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

And here is my setup:

```py
from langchain.llms.base import LLM
import torch

class CustomLLM(LLM):
    model_name = "upstage/llama-65b-instruct"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=True, skip_special_tokens=True)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        device_map="auto",
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        load_in_8bit=True,
        rope_scaling={"type": "dynamic", "factor": 2}  # allows handling of longer inputs
    )

    def _call(self, prompt, stop=None, **kwargs):
        prompt = f"### User:\n{prompt}\n\n### Assistant:\n"
        inputs = self.tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(self.model.device)
        output = self.model.generate(**inputs, streamer=self.streamer, use_cache=True, max_new_tokens=float('inf'))
        return self.tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

    @property
    def _identifying_params(self):
        return {"name_of_model": self.model_name}

    @property
    def _llm_type(self):
        return "custom"


llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=CustomLLM())
```

I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my existing setup or if any additional steps or configurations are needed to fix this issue. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Llama2 70b models you need at least 40GB of VRAM. You only have 24 GB: `23.64 GiB total capacity`.

Some options:

- (Recommended always) Use a model that has been quantised (i.e. reduced in size without losing much in performance). [TheBloke's](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke) hugging face page has 100s of such models you can use for free e.g. [TheBloke/Llama-2-70B-chat-GPTQ](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-70B-chat-GPTQ) only takes up 35 GB. Using an unquantised 70b model would take up 135 GB.
- Use a smaller model (in terms of parameters)
- Rent a GPU with more memory

If you want to use the biggest model, rent a GPU (I like vast.ai) and pick the quantised version. As of Oct 2023, it costs $0.40/hour to rent an A40 GPU with 48GB VRAM which can comfortably run Llama2-70b.